# Grep is working differently accessing a server from different machines

Tags: linux, grep

I have a file with values separated by tabs. When a value is not present I put a '-' in the corresponding field.

Each line begins with an identifier. I'm simply searching for lines corresponding to given identifier and, using **grep** on a machine A (Linux) from two different machine (B and C) and two different results appear. In particular from one of the machines some consecutives '-' are missing.
The two machines are one with linux ubuntu (B) and the other with MAC OSX (C).
Here is an example:

INPUT FILE:

```
comp10034_c0_seq1   281 -   UniRef90_B7GCX2 276 3e-29   640 98.220640569395 13.90625    Predicted_protein   Phaeodactylum_tricornutum   -   -   GO:0006200  ATP_catabolic_process   GO:0005524  ATP
 binding    GO:0016020  membrane    pfam00005   138-230 1.00e-09    -   -   -   93  -   0   0.136126    0   
comp10036_c0_seq1   315 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   77  +   2   0.00277103  0   
comp10037_c0_seq1   350 -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   77  +   2   0.738719    0   
comp6261_c0_seq1    1227    -   UniRef90_K0R0D8 519 1e-82   186 42.2982885085575    98.9247311827957    Uncharacterized_protein Thalassiosira_ oceanica -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  350 +   1   0.0034993   0
```

GREP FROM MACHINE B

```
grep 'comp6261_c0_seq1' file.txt
```

RESULT:

```
comp6261_c0_seq1    1227    -   UniRef90_K0R0D8 519 1e-82   186 42.2982885085575    98.9247311827957    Uncharacterized_protein Thalassiosira_oceanica  -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   -   --  350 +   1   0.0034993   0
```

GREP FROM MACHINE C

```
grep 'comp6261_c0_seq1' file.txt
```

RESULT:

```
comp6261_c0_seq1    1227    -   UniRef90_K0R0D8 519 1e-82   186 42.2982885085575    98.9247311827957    Uncharacterized_protein Thalassiosira_oceanica  -   350 +   1   0.0034993   0
```

P.S.
Here in the forum tabs are not viewable so I chosen to write words separated by spaces.

Comment: 100% sure that `file.txt` is the same on both machines? Have you diffed them?

Comment: @hek2mgl I'd probably use a checksum, like `md5sum`.  Still, that would have been my first question.  The file being generated differently, being converted during file transfer or just having been modified on that one machine is the most likely case.

Comment: What shell are you using, what versions of grep? what OS are machine1 and machine2

Comment: I already added a comment some days ago but it is not there. I was wrong. Me and my supervisor we are accessing the same machine with the file. The grep is on the same machine. The only difference is that I'm accesing with ubuntu and him with OSX

Comment: When you say "accessing with ubuntu", what do you mean? Is it a remote filesystem mount, or are you using ssh, or something else? It seems like maybe the difference is not in the output of the grep but in the terminal where you are viewing it. `grep ... | md5sum` would tell you if it's really different.

Comment: Yes, I'm accessing the os by using ssh on both machines.

Answer (score 0):

Either your input files are different on each machine, or your input file contains control characters that are interpreted differently on each machine. Run `diff` and `cat -v` on your input files to discover which is true.

Answer (score 0):

If the files are identical, perhaps the grep isn't. Check to see if your `grep` is a link, alias or builtin (a shell function). Try running:

```
which grep
`which grep` 'comp6261_c0_seq1' file.txt
```